# Jquery datepicker and modal in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datepicker

For some reason I am experiencing wierd inconsistancies with IE and Firefox when using a modal box plus datepicker. Here is the full example code - does anyone know how to get IE to shut the calendar when you click on a date? Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>                                     
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var date_settings = { 
          closeText: 'Close',
          minDate: 0, 
          maxDate: new Date(2014,12,11), 
          buttonImage: "/images/jquery_ui/datepicker.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: false,
            prevText: '&laquo;',
            nextText: '&raquo;',
            currentText: 'Current',
            monthNames: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'         
        };

        var diag_settings = {
          height: 630,
          width:  750,
          modal: true,
          title: 'Post schedule',
          autoOpen: false, 
        };

        $(document).ready(function(){  
          $('input[name="schedule_date"]').datepicker(date_settings);
          $('.sel_date').datepicker(date_settings);

          $("#scheduling").dialog(diag_settings);
          $("#scheduling").dialog('open');

        });

        </script>         
        <div id="scheduling">  
                <div id="primary"> 
                        <input type="text" id="schedule_date" name="schedule_date" style="width:190px;" class="sendWith" value="11/12/2014" /> 
                </div>
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look there is an article here that works:

> http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/06/18/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-focus-fix/

Does the date picker behave good without the modal box? the problem seems related just to datepicker and not to the interaction with modal box.

The problem is that you require there $.browser function that is not there.
Anyway the problem looks like an internet explorer glitch.
Changing this code solves the problem partially, even removing the $.browser function, but it forces you to blur and select and blur and select to open the datepicker after close.

```
var date_settings = { 
  closeText: 'Close',
  minDate: 0, 
  maxDate: new Date(2014,12,11), 
  buttonImage: "/images/jquery_ui/datepicker.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: false,
  prevText: '&laquo;',
  nextText: '&raquo;',
  currentText: 'Current',
  monthNames: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
  dayNamesMin: ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  /* fix buggy IE focus functionality */
  fixFocusIE: false,

  /* blur needed to correctly handle placeholder text */
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        this.fixFocusIE = true;
  },
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        this.fixFocusIE = true;
  },
  beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        var result = $.browser.msie ? !this.fixFocusIE : true;
        this.fixFocusIE = false;
        return result;
  }
};
```

Look even this question is similar

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689675/datepicker-using-jquery-loses-focus-to-the-textbox-after-date-selected
```

If it doesn't work, just remove $.browser part, that is not available in your particular setup:

```
var date_settings = { 
  closeText: 'Close',
  minDate: 0, 
  maxDate: new Date(2014,12,11), 
  buttonImage: "/images/jquery_ui/datepicker.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: false,
  prevText: '&laquo;',
  nextText: '&raquo;',
  currentText: 'Current',
  monthNames: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
  dayNamesMin: ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  /* fix buggy IE focus functionality */
  fixFocusIE: false,

  /* blur needed to correctly handle placeholder text */
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        this.fixFocusIE = true;
  },
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        this.fixFocusIE = true;
  },
  beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        var result = !this.fixFocusIE;
        this.fixFocusIE = false;
        return result;
  }
};
```

If you don't have $.browser functionality you can add adding this code in your javascript file, when you are sure the document ( and jquery with it ) is loaded.

```
jQuery.uaMatch = function( ua ) {
    ua = ua.toLowerCase();

    var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
        [];

    return {
        browser: match[ 1 ] || "",
        version: match[ 2 ] || "0"
    };
};

// Don't clobber any existing jQuery.browser in case it's different
if ( !jQuery.browser ) {
    matched = jQuery.uaMatch( navigator.userAgent );
    browser = {};

    if ( matched.browser ) {
        browser[ matched.browser ] = true;
        browser.version = matched.version;
    }

    // Chrome is Webkit, but Webkit is also Safari.
    if ( browser.chrome ) {
        browser.webkit = true;
    } else if ( browser.webkit ) {
        browser.safari = true;
    }

    jQuery.browser = browser;
}
```

Look for an example here:
    http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/a.html
Internet explorer still doing mess, to REOPEN the calendar you have to defocus the input and refocus it. Other browsers are fine.

Comment: Sorry but I've overwritten my date_settings with yours and now the datepicker doesn't even load.

Comment: Remove 
var result = $.browser.msie ? !this.fixFocusIE : true;
leave
var result = !this.fixFocusIE;

but would be better you add $.browser function to your jquery for this problem

Comment: I use jquery 1.11.1 min so removing code from the core is a bit of a pain and I thought this had come out from Jquery anyway.

Comment: You can add to the page the code for $.browser. is very short.

Comment: Could you amend your answer to include the full code needed inc the $.browser code? Thanks.

Comment: Ok - I have managed to get option 2 of your code blocks to work solo. However what I've now found is another wierd thing - if you click into the input box the datepicker won't reload however if you click on the *very* edge of the input box it will re-load. It might be helpful to see a full example from my original if poss.

Comment: I added a working example, sort of. I don't know if you can avoid this internet explorer glitch eaisy.

Comment: Thank you for your time on it - obviously this one is a bit of a pain!

Comment: Internet explorer is a little bit of pain itself. IMHO. anyway if i helped you, just accept the answer, or vote it up, or do both. :)